# How can I find records that are not the latest and without a specific value for a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of payment records for contracts. Each contract is paid by monthly payments.

The table has following fields:

- ID (automatically assigned when a payment record is created)
- payment_number (character array of digits, incremented over months, e.g. "1", "2", "3")
- payment_status ("Received", "Rejected", "Approved", "Processed")
- contract_ID (character array of letters and digits)

I have a theory that when a new payment is received, the previous payment must have been processed.
A month is long enough for processing the previous payment.

In order to verify that, I was wondering how to find counterexamples.
More specifically, in the payment records for each contract, how can I find all the payment records which are not the latest payments for the contract but with statuses not "Processed".

```
ID   contract_ID  payment_number payment_status
1    contract1      1           Processed
2    contract1      2           Processed
3    contract2      1          Processed
4    contract2      2           Approved
5    contract1      3           Received
6    contract2      3           Processed
```

Comment: `where exists (payment with same contract_ID and greater ID) and status <> 'Processed'`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick that I employ in various forms from time to time:

```
with cte as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by contract_ID order by id desc) as rn
    from (values 
        (1, 'contract1', 1, 'Processed'),
        (2, 'contract1', 2, 'Processed'),
        (3, 'contract2', 1, 'Processed'),
        (4, 'contract2', 2, 'Approved'),
        (5, 'contract1', 3, 'Received'),
        (6, 'contract2', 3, 'Processed')
    ) as d(ID, contract_ID, payment_number, payment_status)
)
select *
from cte
where rn <> 1
    and payment_status <> 'Processed';
```

The bulk of the solution is in adding a `row_number()` column. What that does is enumerate the rows within each contract (`partition by contract_id`) in order from newest to oldest (`order by id desc`). Once you have that, expressing your logic ("is not the newest" and "has status other than 'Processed'") is easily expressible with SQL predicates.

Comment: Thanks. How can I also get the contract groups of payments that contain such payments.?

Comment: Use the above as a basis to identify the groups. The most simple would be `select * from cte where contract_id in («select from above»)` (except doing `select contract_ID` instead of `select *` in the subquery).

Comment: Thanks. 
My theory has been updated. I suspected that the status of a payment can't be more advanced than the status of its previous payment. For example, if the previous payment has status "Received", then the status of the payment can only be "Received".
I was wondering how to find all the counter examples in the table?
(Maybe also the contract group of payments containing counter examples, so that I can see the statuses of counter example payments and of their previous payments)

Comment: To paraphrase Fermat - this comment box is too narrow to contain what is effectively a new problem. Feel free to create a new question with the relevant details (I can see some subtlety around how you want various statuses ordered) and link it here.

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72959402/how-can-i-find-records-that-are-out-of-order-with-respect-to-its-previous-record