# How can I find records that are out of order with respect to its previous record and a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of payment records for contracts. Each contract is paid by monthly payments. The table has following fields:

- ID (automatically assigned when a payment record is created)
- payment_number (character array of digits, incremented over months, e.g. "1", "2", "3")
- payment_status ("Received", "Rejected", "Approved", "Processed")
- contract_ID (character array of letters and digits)

I suspected that the status of a payment can't be more advanced than the status of its previous payment. For example, if the previous payment has status "Received", then the status of the payment can only be "Received".

I was wondering how to find all the counter examples in the table?
(Maybe also the contract group of payments containing counter examples, so that I can see the statuses of counter example payments and of their previous payments).

```
ID   contract_ID  payment_number payment_status
1    contract1      1           Processed
2    contract1      2           Received
3    contract2      1          Processed
4    contract2      2           Approved
5    contract1      3           Approved
6    contract2      3           Processed
```

I expect it outputs something like:

```
 ID   contract_ID  payment_number payment_status
2    contract1      2           Received
5    contract1      3           Approved
```

and

```
ID   contract_ID  payment_number payment_status
4    contract2      2           Approved
6    contract2      3        Processed
```

Comment: A table has columns, not fields. What do you mean with "character array"? Why is `payment_number` not an integer? Why don't you have a datetime column for when the payment was made? What do you mean with a "more advanced status"? I don't understand what you are asking, and with 88k+ rep you should know how to ask a good question that doesn't leave any doubt what you need, what the table(s) you work with look like, what data is in them, what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: And [the exact same question at pretty much the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72952564/how-can-i-find-records-that-are-not-the-latest-and-without-a-specific-value-for)

Answer (score 3):

Taking this question on its individual merit and allowing for certain misgivings and ambiguities as mentioned in the comments, I think this is an easily comprehended solution:

```sql
create table #payments 
(
   id int, 
   contract_ID varchar(20), 
   payment_number int, 
   payment_status varchar(20)
);

insert   #payments(id, contract_id, payment_number, payment_status)
values   (1, 'contract1', 1, 'Processed'),
         (2, 'contract1', 2, 'Received'),
         (3, 'contract2', 1, 'Processed'),
         (4, 'contract2', 2, 'Approved'),
         (5, 'contract1', 3, 'Approved'),
         (6, 'contract2', 3, 'Processed');

-- provide an ordering to the statuses according to the question text. 
-- assumption: rejected/approved sit in the same lifecycle position and are mutually exclusive
with payments as
(
   select   p.*, t.statusIndex
   from     #payments         p
   join     (
               values   ('Received', 0),
                        ('Rejected', 1),
                        ('Approved', 1),
                        ('Processed', 2)
            ) t (payment_status, statusIndex) on t.payment_status = p.payment_status  
)

select         p.id,
               p.contract_ID,
               invalid_payment_number = p.payment_number,
               invalid_payment_status = p.payment_status,
               prior_payment_number = pp.payment_number,
               prior_payment_status = pp.payment_status
from           payments p
cross apply    (
                  select   pp.payment_number, pp.payment_status
                  from     payments    pp
                  where    pp.contract_id = p.contract_id
                           and pp.payment_number < p.payment_number
                           and pp.statusIndex >= p.statusIndex
               ) pp
order by       p.contract_id,
               p.payment_number;
```

The logic of this query, in "plain English", is:

For all payments:
find any "prior" payment rows (rows which have the same `contractId`,
and which have a lower `payment_number`),
and where the prior payment row has a status which is logically later or equal to the status of this payment, given the possible lifecycle of the payment.

If any such rows are found, return the original row along with the prior payment row or rows, since these represent "invalid" logical progressions.